# how do I read this text file in pieces?

Tags: php

hi I need to read a text file and then explode it to two piece then match it with give name then dispay if it matches...so far the code I made is given below..but it doesnt work..can any one tell me what wrong is with this code??

```
$name = "thomas";
$filename = file("land.txt");
//$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
for($i=0; $i<count($filename); $i++)
        {
            $string = explode(":", $filename[$i]);

            if($name == $string[1])
                $id = $string[0];
        }

echo $id;
```

this case it should display "D1"; but it doesnt!!

content of `"land.txt"` file

```
D1:thomas
D6:benny
D7:alwyn
D25:mathew
D9:peter
```

Comment: what does var_dump($filename); return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$filename = file("land.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Or

```
$string = explode(":", trim($filename[$i]));
```

What is [FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Comment: Result of `explode` is not a string, you should use `list($string) = explode(...` or just `$string[0]` to get the desired result.

Comment: thanks this works great well I forgot to add trim...but why we need that??

Answer (score 0):

Over here

`if($name == $string[1]) use if($name == trim($string[1]))` .

Try this and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $name = 'thomas';
  $content = file('land.txt');
  $id = NULL;
  foreach($content as $no => $line){
   $array = explode(':', $line);
   if($array[1] == $name)
     $id = $array[0];
  }
  echo $id;
```